# Como guardar los datos de un a funcion for en un arraylist o almacenar todos los datos seperados en uno solo? en angular

Tags: angular

He creado una función que recorre un array y me devuelve los nombres. El caso es que me trae por separado como se observa en la imagen  y lo que quiero hacer es tener todos esos datos por separado en una sola

```js
 for (var i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {
      var obj = dat[i];
      console.log("datos:", obj.firstname);
   
   

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola José, te recomiendo que completes el [tour] de bienvenida para que conozcas cómo se espera que las preguntas esté formuladas. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir los detalles o datos que consideres útiles para que podamos entender tu problema.

Comment: A ver si te he entendido: tienes un array con objetos (personas, por lo que veo) y quieres tener un array sólo con los nombres de estas personas, ¿es correcto?

Comment: sii solo quiero los nombres en un solo array por que como ves me recorre el array pero por separado

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar el método [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map), que te permitirá crear un nuevo array con los datos obtenidos del primero. Te pongo un ejemplo:

```js
const usuarios = [
  { name: "user1", age: 21 },
  { name: "user2", age: 22 },
  { name: "user3", age: 23 }
  
]

const nombres = usuarios.map(usuario => usuario.name);

console.log(nombres);
```